# Is there any AWS setup that can associate a fixed IP to a domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ip-address

I need to create a security group that allows traffic between an EC2 instance and a certain domain.

Problem is, the IP associated to a domain can change (or there can be multiple IPs), so I can't create a security group.

Is there any AWS service/setup to have the EC2 instance connect to a fixed IP, that then connects to the given domain?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any AWS service/setup to have the EC2 instance connect to a fixed IP

You can associate [Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) with your instance:

> An Elastic IP address is a **public IPv4 address**, which is reachable from the internet. If your instance does not have a public IPv4 address, you can associate an Elastic IP address with your instance to enable communication with the internet. For example, this allows you to connect to your instance from your local computer.

What's more, [EIP is free](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/) as long as:

- The Elastic IP address is associated with an EC2 instance.
- The instance associated with the Elastic IP address is running.
- The instance has only one Elastic IP address attached to it.

Having the EIP you can associate it with a domain through an `A` record.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can assign a fix ip address to ec2 instance using "Elastic ip"
To allocate an Elastic IP and associate it with an Ec2 instance follow below steps:

Go to ec2 dashboard click on elastic IPS under Network & security then click on Allocate Elastic IP address and click Allocate

Once an IP is allocated you need to associate it with the EC2 Instance
Click ip address and go to Actions and choose Associate Elastic IP address.
In the Resource type choose Instance and and choose the instance from the dropdown on the Instance field and click Associate.